# Using s command to subsitute variables

Tags: regex, perl, text-processing, substitution

I need to replace a incorrect Illumina fasta header for formatting in QIIME, and this script doesn't quite work like I want. I need to able to put in variables and use the unix "s" command. Any ideas?

```
print 'What is the exact sequence of characters to replace? ';
chomp (my $seq_char = <> );
print 'What is the new label to attach? ';
chomp (my $label = <> );

while( $seq = $seq_in->next_seq() )
{
        my $seqName = $seq->id;
        $seqName =~ s/\'$seq_char'/\'$label' /g; #replace original characters with new label
        $seqName =~ s/(gi\.\w*)\..*/$1/;
```

Comment: There are no 's' command, it's more like an expression that look for certain patterns and replace them with a different specified string. What is the patter that you need change in your fasta header?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. 1) There is no such thing as a UNIX `s` command; you probably mean Perl's `s///` operator. 2) You need to show us your input and your desired output. 3) You need to explain exactly how your script is failing in order for us to be able to help. 4) You need to explain how the script is executed, with what parameters. 5) You need to show all of the relevant lines. What is the `next_seq()` function? Where is `$seq` defined? Please [edit] your question to address these issues.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some stray single quotes in there:

```
my $seqName = "foobar";
my $seq_char = "foo";
my $label = "HELLO";
$seqName =~ s/\Q$seq_char/$label/g;
say $seqName;
```

```
HELLObar
```

Try to stick with one variable style: you have `camelCase` and `word_style` -- this is a personal preference, but pick one and stick with it.

See also: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the `sed` command?

You can do it with a Bash one-liner also:
`cat {your_file} | sed 's/\(gi\.\w*\)\..*/\1/' | sed 's/$seq_char/$label /g'`

Please note the regex pattern, for instance:

```
echo gi.1234562.123124 | sed 's/\(gi\.\w*\)\..*/\1/'
```

outputs

```
gi.1234562
```

And that a space will be inserted with `sed 's/$seq_char/$label /g'`